# react-navigation native-stack, how to change the modal height?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-native-stack

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-unstable-nested-components */
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import PersonalNewSecurity from './screens/PersonalNewSecurity';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import SelectLocation from './screens/SelectLocation';
import CameraScreen from './screens/CameraScreen';
import HomeToCheckOut from './screens/HomeToCheckOut';
import HomeAfterCheckOut from './screens/HomeAfterCheckout';
import ScanQR from './screens/ScanQR';
import DetailCheckIn from './screens/DetailCheckIn';
import DetailCheckOut from './screens/DetailCheckOut';
import UpdateAccount from './screens/UpdateAccount';
import Others from './screens/OthersScreen';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
          } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
            iconName = focused
              ? 'account-circle-outline'
              : 'account-circle-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'ScanQR') {
            iconName = focused ? 'qrcode-scan' : 'qrcode-scan';
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <Icon
              name={iconName}
              size={size}
              color={color}
            />
          );
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E5E7EB' },
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={DetailCheckOut}
        // options={{ tabBarBadge: 3, headerShown: false }}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ScanQR"
        component={StackNavigator}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={PersonalNewSecurity}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function StackNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        presentation: 'modal', // or formSheet
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Select Location"
        component={SelectLocation}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Other Location"
        component={Others}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function RootStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

navigation.js

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function OthersScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View className={'ml-4 p-3 mr-4 mt-1'}>
      <Text className={'text-3xl font-bold'}>Other Location</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mt-4 mb-1'}>Latitude: 19.67</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mb-1'}>Longitude: 100.34</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mb-1'}>Timestamp: 2022-08-21 12:30 PM</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mt-4 font-bold'}>Remarks</Text>
      <TextInput
        className={'mt-1 border rounded-lg p-7'}
        placeholder="Please enter reamarks here"
        placeholderTextColor="#000"
      />
      <View className={'mt-4 items-center flex-row space-x-5 '}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          className={'p-3 w-40 items-center justify-center border rounded-lg'}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        >
          <Text className={'text-sm'}>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          className={
            'bg-gray-400 p-3 w-40 items-center justify-center rounded-lg'
          }
        >
          <Text className={'text-sm text-white'}>Check-In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

otherscreen.js

[this is my current screen for modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHJ4v.png)

i wannna make like this
[this is my target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEjsu.jpg)

is there any possible to change the height using the react-navigation native-stack v6? i already look at the documentation which it does not mention any styling which can change the height of modal

im expecting the height of modal can be change

Answer (score 0):

Adding a  to the root of my app seemed to interfere with the  that was already there (which already uses PortalProvider under the hood). Only every other bottom sheet I opened would become visible.

I got mine working simply by wrapping my react-navigation modal screen's contents in a :

```
 function AppStack() {
            return (
                <NativeStack.Navigator>
                    {/* ... */}
                    <NativeStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
                        <NativeStack.Screen 
                            name="MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal" 
                            component={MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal} 
                        />
                    </NativeStack.Group>
                </NativeStack.Navigator>
            )
        }
    
function 
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BottomSheetModalProvider, BottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal: undefined;
};

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal'>;

const MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  const handleOpenBottomSheetModal = () => {
    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
  };

  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button title="Open Bottom Sheet Modal" onPress={handleOpenBottomSheetModal} />
      </View>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={[300, 200, 0]} // Define your desired snap points here
      >
        {/* Content of your bottom sheet modal */}
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 16 }}>
          {/* Your bottom sheet modal content here */}
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
};

export default MyScreenThatNeedsToBeAbleToOpenABottomSheetModal;
```

Comment: i already did based on your code, however the height still same as picture given. My expectation is i want to control the height modal. <BottomSheetModalProvider> for this one, which library that you used?

Comment: I just update please try it should work

Comment: thanks for update, however i want to use library react-navigation. i dont want to use other library

Answer (score 0):

The modal's height should now match the value you entered in the styles' height attribute.modalCard object.

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalCard: {
    height: 400, // Set the desired height here
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});

export default function OthersScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View className={'ml-4 p-3 mr-4 mt-1'}>
      <Text className={'text-3xl font-bold'}>Other Location</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mt-4 mb-1'}>Latitude: 19.67</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mb-1'}>Longitude: 100.34</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mb-1'}>Timestamp: 2022-08-21 12:30 PM</Text>
      <Text className={'text-sm mt-4 font-bold'}>Remarks</Text>
      <TextInput
        className={'mt-1 border rounded-lg p-7'}
        placeholder="Please enter reamarks here"
        placeholderTextColor="#000"
      />
      <View className={'mt-4 items-center flex-row space-x-5 '}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          className={'p-3 w-40 items-center justify-center border rounded-lg'}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        >
          <Text className={'text-sm'}>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          className={
            'bg-gray-400 p-3 w-40 items-center justify-center rounded-lg'
          }
        >
          <Text className={'text-sm text-white'}>Check-In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

<Stack.Screen
  name="Other Location"
  component={Others}
  options={{
    headerShown: false,
    cardStyle: styles.modalCard,
  }}
/>
```